How does kubernetes guarantee the number of pods in replicaset
Suppose I have a deployment (with replicaset underlying) and set the replica count to 1, how does (or does) kubernetes guarantee there's at most one pod in the cluster?
One corner case is:

A node cannot talk to controller manager with heartbeat;
So controller manager considers it dead and updates current replica count to 0 at etcd;
A new pod is created by controller manager via kubelet, so there're two pods in the cluster.


If you want to make sure that it will first delete the old pod and only then create a new one, you can set the strategy type to Recreate or consider switching to STS instead of Deployment

Refer this official Kubernetes Document1 and Document2 which may helps to resolve your issue.

Thank you for the response! But I still have one confusion, doesn't kubernetes controller manager treats "unresponsive alive pod" and "already dead and non-existent pod" as the same thing? So even if I set the update strategy, there's still chance there're two pods at the same time?

One thing I'm thinking: if (1) kubelet has a timeout to kill pod (i.e. if cannot connect to controller manager in X seconds, then kill the pod); (2) controller manager waits for the timeout to make sure pod will be killed; (3) start a new pod, that should guarantee only one pod
